# How do I implement social media authorizations in the Wix ADI using JavaScript in Velo?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, velo

I'm working on a [Wix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wix.com) website where users can connect their social media accounts and have data from them displayed on their profile pages.

Currently, the form just asks them to input their social media URLs. Obviously, this is a problem, as there's no way for to verify that these accounts actually belong to them. **How can I have them sign in to their social accounts to have them verify that they own the accounts from within the sign-up form?**

Currently I'm having them connect their YouTube, [Twitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitch_(service)), Instagram, and [TikTok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TikTok) accounts. I imagine there's some kind of  OAuth solution, but I just don’t know what. It is *critical* to the function of the site that we are 100% sure the connected accounts are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it in Velo unless you have a very specific reason.
The [Wix ADI](https://support.wix.com/en/article/about-wix-adi) natively supports it [(refer to here)](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-forum-enabling-or-disabling-social-login).
And as for other things like TikTok, that can be done by writing Node.js backend code:

[image: Place to find it]

Comment: it looks like this only works for google and facebook

Comment: but you can impliment additional oauth by writing backend code in node.js (see picture above) and writing oauth code can only be done by reading the docs